# Java Error on token "}" expected "{"

Tags: java, arrays, syntax

So I'm in the midst of creating a gambling application and just as I'm about to close up for the night. I see there is a new error all the way at the bottom with my closing brackets.

I'm getting the following error `Syntax on error "{", "}" expected.`

I think there might be an issue with one of my methods, but all of the brackets seem to be placed correctly. I apologize that it's 200+ lines of code, but if someone could possibly point out where I went wrong to get this error, I'd really appreciate it. I've tried messing with my brackets, but that only seems to lead to further errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Project2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    int colmax = 2;
    double balance = 2500.0;
    double bet1 = 0;
    double bet2 = 0;
    double profit1 = (bet1 * 2) - bet1;
    double profit2 = (bet2 * 5) - bet2;

    String kBet = null;
    System.out.println("          -==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-"          );
    System.out.println("-==-==-=={ Welcome to the Marist Casino! }==-==-==-");
    System.out.println("          -==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-"          );

    System.out.println("(1) Red Fox Roullete");
    System.out.println("(2) Crash");
    System.out.println("(3) Blackjack");
    System.out.print("Enter the number for the game you'd like to play!: ");
        int game = input.nextInt();

if(game == 1) {
   do {
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Red Fox Roullete!");
    System.out.print("Please choose Black or Red....and a number from 1-10: ");
    String color = input.next();
    int number = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Your available balance is $"+balance+". How much would you like to bet on "+color+"?");
    bet1 = input.nextInt();
    balance -= bet1;
    System.out.print("Your available balance is $"+balance+". How much would you like to bet on "+number+"?");
    bet2 = input.nextInt();
    balance -= bet2;

    System.out.println("------------------------------BET INFO------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("You just bet $"+bet1+" on "+color+" and $"+bet2+" on number "+number);
    System.out.println("Spinning............");
    System.out.println("------------------------------RESULTS-------------------------------------");

    Random rouletteNum = new Random();
    int rNum = min + rouletteNum.nextInt(max);
    int rCol = min + rouletteNum.nextInt(colmax);

    if (rCol == 1) {
        System.out.println("The machine landed on Black "+rNum);
    }
    else if(rCol != 1) {
        System.out.println("The machine landed on Red "+rNum);
    }

    if(rNum == number) {
        System.out.println("Congrats, you guessed the right number! You've won $"+profit2);
            balance += (bet2 * 5);
    }
    else if(rNum != number) {
        System.out.println("Sorry!You didnt guess the right number! You've lost "+bet2);
    }

    if(rCol == 1 && color.equals("Black")) {
        System.out.println("Congrats, you guessed the right color! You've won $"+profit1);
            balance += bet1 * 2 - bet1;
    }
    else if(rCol == 2 && color.equals("Red")) {
        System.out.println("Congrats, you guessed the right color! You've won $"+profit1);
            balance += bet1 * 2 - bet1;
    }       
    if(rCol == 2 && color.equals("Black")) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't guess the right color. You've lost $"+bet1);
    }
    else if(rCol == 1 && color.equals("Red")) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't guess the right color. You've lost $"+bet1);
    }


    System.out.println("After the bet, you're updated balance is $"+balance);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Yes or No? Would you like to place another bet in Roulette?");
        kBet = input.next();
    }
   while(kBet.equals("Yes"));
     if(kBet.equals("No")) {
        System.out.println("(1) Red Fox Roullete");
        System.out.println("(2) Blackjack");
        System.out.println("(3) Crash");
        System.out.print("Enter the number for the game you'd like to play!: ");
            game = input.nextInt();
} 

    }
    //CRASH
else if (game == 2) {
    do {
         int bet = 0;
         double start = 1.00;
         double crashValue = 1.00;
         int stopGame = 1;
         double cashout = 0;
         System.out.println("-------------------CRASH GAME--------------------------");
         System.out.println("Welcome to Crash!");
         System.out.print("What number would you like to cashout at?(Ex. 1.15):");
            cashout = input.nextDouble();
         System.out.print("Your balance is $"+balance+". How much would you like to bet on this round?:");
            bet = input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         System.out.println("Round is beginning........."); 

         for(int i =0; i < stopGame; i++) {
    do {
         double crash = Math.random() * 100;
         if (crash < 95) {
             start += .01;
             System.out.printf("%.2f\n",start);
         }
         else if(crash > 95) {
                 i++;
                 crashValue = start;
                 System.out.println("----------------------------RESULTS--------------------------------");
                 System.out.print("CRASH! The game crashed at "); 
                 System.out.printf("%.2f",start);
                 System.out.println("x"); 
         }
    } 
    while(i == 0);
   }
    if(cashout < crashValue) {
        System.out.println("Congrats! You cashed out at "+cashout+" before the game crashed. You've won $"+bet*cashout);
        balance += bet * cashout;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry! The game crashed before you could cash out. You've lost $"+bet);
        balance -= bet;
    }
    System.out.println("After your bet, you're updated balance is $"+balance);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Yes or No? Would you like to play another round of Crash?: ");
     kBet = input.next();
}  
   while(kBet.equals("Yes"));
   if(kBet.equals("No")) {
        System.out.println("(1) Red Fox Roullete");
        System.out.println("(2) Blackjack");
        System.out.println("(3) Crash");
        System.out.print("Enter the number for the game you'd like to play!: ");
            game = input.nextInt();
     }
   }
//BlackJack Game
else if(game == 3) {
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("---------------------Black Jack--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack!");
    System.out.println("Available balance is $"+balance);
    System.out.print("How much would you like to bet on this hand?: ");
    int bet = input.nextInt();
    balance -= bet;
    System.out.println("You just bet $"+bet+"......Dealing cards!");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
    String pCard1 = dealCard();
    String pCard2 = dealCard();
    int value1 = getCardValue(pCard1);
    int value2 = getCardValue(pCard2);

    System.out.println("Your hand is a "+pCard1+" and a "+pCard2);
    System.out.print("Would you like to Hit or Stand?: ");
    String HitOrStand = input.next();
    }
}
    public static String dealCard() {
    int rCard = (int)Math.random() * 14;
    switch(rCard) {
    case 1 : return "2";
    case 2 : return "3";
    case 3 : return "4";
    case 4 : return "5";
    case 5 : return "6";
    case 6 : return "7";
    case 7 : return "8";
    case 8 : return "9";
    case 9 : return "10";
    case 10 : return "Queen";
    case 11 : return "Jack";
    case 12 : return "King";
    case 13 : return "Ace";
    }
}
    public static int getCardValue(String x) {
        if(x.equals("2")) {
            return 2;
        }
        if(x.equals("3")) {
            return 3;
        }
        if(x.equals("4")) {
            return 4;
        }
        if(x.equals("5")) {
            return 5;
        }
        if(x.equals("6")) {
            return 6;
        }
        if(x.equals("7")) {
            return 7;
        }
        if(x.equals("8")) {
            return 8;
        }
        if(x.equals("9")) {
            return 9;
        }
        if(x.equals("10")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if(x.equals("Queen")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if(x.equals("Jack")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if(x.equals("King")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if(x.equals("Ace")) {
            return 11;
        }

    }
   }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Seriously: get an IDE that does code formatting and displays errors inline with the code.  It'll find unbalanced braces quickly and easily.

Comment: You have 2 extra brackets at the end, and after that you'll find that you're missing a few returns. As @markspace said - get an IDE (Eclipse and NetBeans are free), or at least a good editor (VS Code, Atom, Sublime,...) and things like this won't happen.
Also, the compiler wars you which line number is the problem, if you can enable line numbers wherever you write code (and you probably can), it's already a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two more brackets and two missing return:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Project2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int min = 1;
    int max = 10;
    int colmax = 2;
    double balance = 2500.0;
    double bet1 = 0;
    double bet2 = 0;
    double profit1 = (bet1 * 2) - bet1;
    double profit2 = (bet2 * 5) - bet2;

    String kBet = null;
    System.out.println("          -==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-"          );
    System.out.println("-==-==-=={ Welcome to the Marist Casino! }==-==-==-");
    System.out.println("          -==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-==-"          );

    System.out.println("(1) Red Fox Roullete");
    System.out.println("(2) Crash");
    System.out.println("(3) Blackjack");
    System.out.print("Enter the number for the game you'd like to play!: ");
        int game = input.nextInt();

if(game == 1) {
   do {
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to Red Fox Roullete!");
    System.out.print("Please choose Black or Red....and a number from 1-10: ");
    String color = input.next();
    int number = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Your available balance is $"+balance+". How much would you like to bet on "+color+"?");
    bet1 = input.nextInt();
    balance -= bet1;
    System.out.print("Your available balance is $"+balance+". How much would you like to bet on "+number+"?");
    bet2 = input.nextInt();
    balance -= bet2;

    System.out.println("------------------------------BET INFO------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("You just bet $"+bet1+" on "+color+" and $"+bet2+" on number "+number);
    System.out.println("Spinning............");
    System.out.println("------------------------------RESULTS-------------------------------------");

    Random rouletteNum = new Random();
    int rNum = min + rouletteNum.nextInt(max);
    int rCol = min + rouletteNum.nextInt(colmax);

    if (rCol == 1) {
        System.out.println("The machine landed on Black "+rNum);
    }
    else if(rCol != 1) {
        System.out.println("The machine landed on Red "+rNum);
    }

    if(rNum == number) {
        System.out.println("Congrats, you guessed the right number! You've won $"+profit2);
            balance += (bet2 * 5);
    }
    else if(rNum != number) {
        System.out.println("Sorry!You didnt guess the right number! You've lost "+bet2);
    }

    if(rCol == 1 && color.equals("Black")) {
        System.out.println("Congrats, you guessed the right color! You've won $"+profit1);
            balance += bet1 * 2 - bet1;
    }
    else if(rCol == 2 && color.equals("Red")) {
        System.out.println("Congrats, you guessed the right color! You've won $"+profit1);
            balance += bet1 * 2 - bet1;
    }       
    if(rCol == 2 && color.equals("Black")) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't guess the right color. You've lost $"+bet1);
    }
    else if(rCol == 1 && color.equals("Red")) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, you didn't guess the right color. You've lost $"+bet1);
    }


    System.out.println("After the bet, you're updated balance is $"+balance);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Yes or No? Would you like to place another bet in Roulette?");
        kBet = input.next();
    }

   while(kBet.equals("Yes"));
     if(kBet.equals("No")) {
        System.out.println("(1) Red Fox Roullete");
        System.out.println("(2) Blackjack");
        System.out.println("(3) Crash");
        System.out.print("Enter the number for the game you'd like to play!: ");
            game = input.nextInt();
} 

    }
    //CRASH
else if (game == 2) {
    do {
         int bet = 0;
         double start = 1.00;
         double crashValue = 1.00;
         int stopGame = 1;
         double cashout = 0;
         System.out.println("-------------------CRASH GAME--------------------------");
         System.out.println("Welcome to Crash!");
         System.out.print("What number would you like to cashout at?(Ex. 1.15):");
            cashout = input.nextDouble();
         System.out.print("Your balance is $"+balance+". How much would you like to bet on this round?:");
            bet = input.nextInt();
         System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");
         System.out.println("Round is beginning........."); 

         for(int i =0; i < stopGame; i++) {
    do {
         double crash = Math.random() * 100;
         if (crash < 95) {
             start += .01;
             System.out.printf("%.2f\n",start);
         }
         else if(crash > 95) {
                 i++;
                 crashValue = start;
                 System.out.println("----------------------------RESULTS--------------------------------");
                 System.out.print("CRASH! The game crashed at "); 
                 System.out.printf("%.2f",start);
                 System.out.println("x"); 
         }
    } 
    while(i == 0);
   }
    if(cashout < crashValue) {
        System.out.println("Congrats! You cashed out at "+cashout+" before the game crashed. You've won $"+bet*cashout);
        balance += bet * cashout;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Sorry! The game crashed before you could cash out. You've lost $"+bet);
        balance -= bet;
    }
    System.out.println("After your bet, you're updated balance is $"+balance);
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.print("Yes or No? Would you like to play another round of Crash?: ");
     kBet = input.next();
}  
   while(kBet.equals("Yes"));
   if(kBet.equals("No")) {
        System.out.println("(1) Red Fox Roullete");
        System.out.println("(2) Blackjack");
        System.out.println("(3) Crash");
        System.out.print("Enter the number for the game you'd like to play!: ");
            game = input.nextInt();
     }
   }
//BlackJack Game
else if(game == 3) {
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("---------------------Black Jack--------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to BlackJack!");
    System.out.println("Available balance is $"+balance);
    System.out.print("How much would you like to bet on this hand?: ");
    int bet = input.nextInt();
    balance -= bet;
    System.out.println("You just bet $"+bet+"......Dealing cards!");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------");
    String pCard1 = dealCard();
    String pCard2 = dealCard();
    int value1 = getCardValue(pCard1);
    int value2 = getCardValue(pCard2);

    System.out.println("Your hand is a "+pCard1+" and a "+pCard2);
    System.out.print("Would you like to Hit or Stand?: ");
    String HitOrStand = input.next();
    }
}

    public static String dealCard() {
    int rCard = (int)Math.random() * 14;
    switch(rCard) {
    case 1 : return "2";
    case 2 : return "3";
    case 3 : return "4";
    case 4 : return "5";
    case 5 : return "6";
    case 6 : return "7";
    case 7 : return "8";
    case 8 : return "9";
    case 9 : return "10";
    case 10 : return "Queen";
    case 11 : return "Jack";
    case 12 : return "King";
    case 13 : return "Ace";
    }
        return "Unknown";
    }

    public static int getCardValue(String x) {
        if(x.equals("2")) {
            return 2;
        }
        if(x.equals("3")) {
            return 3;
        }
        if(x.equals("4")) {
            return 4;
        }
        if(x.equals("5")) {
            return 5;
        }
        if(x.equals("6")) {
            return 6;
        }
        if(x.equals("7")) {
            return 7;
        }
        if(x.equals("8")) {
            return 8;
        }
        if(x.equals("9")) {
            return 9;
        }
        if(x.equals("10")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if(x.equals("Queen")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if(x.equals("Jack")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if(x.equals("King")) {
            return 10;
        }
        if(x.equals("Ace")) {
            return 11;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```